# how to merge two nodes having "the same father" and having a precise "method" sequence (using XSLT)?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xmlnode

I need to merge the two nodes MANHATTAN:

because our system rule is the following:

"**CREATE** A + **MODIFY** A" is still a "**CREATE** A with the merged attributes"

input file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<world>
<COUNTRY id="USA" >
  <STATE id="NEW JERSEY">
     <CITY id="NEW YORK" method="modify">


        <DISTRICT id="MANHATTAN" method="create">
           <attributes>
              <population>99 </population> 
              <income> 10000</income>
           </attributes>
        </DISTRICT>

        <DISTRICT id="MANHATTAN" method="modify">
           <attributes>
              <temperature>78</temperature>
              <income>15000</income>
              <information>suburb of newyork</information>
           </attributes>
        </DISTRICT>

     </CITY>

  </STATE>
```

Expected output:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <world>
 <COUNTRY id="USA" >
  <STATE id="NEW JERSEY">
     <CITY id="NEW YORK" method="modify">

        <DISTRICT id="MANHATTAN" method="create">
           <attributes>
              <population>99 </population> 
              <temperature>78</temperature>
              <income>15000</income>
              <information>suburb of newyork</information>
           </attributes>
        </DISTRICT>

     </CITY>
 </STATE>
</COUNTRY>
</world>
```

Please help, I have just began XSLT and doing it in Perl or Python will takes hours.

Comment: Will there be two nodes always?

Comment: yes you guessed completely right. The rule is that it will always be 1 CREATE + 1 MODIFY to be transformed into 1 CREATE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adapt solution from similar problem at [how to merge two nodes having "the same father", the same method and the same id=0 (using XSLT)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11426423/how-to-merge-two-nodes-having-the-same-father-the-same-method-and-the-same-id/11429705#11429705)

Read the solution to see how grouping works, and then vary the grouping keys accordingly.